# Mensagem quando ocorre exceção net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

tenho relacionamento 1 pra 1 entre empresa e usuario

mas quando o usuario ja cadastou 1 empresa e tentar cadastrar outra quero mostrar um mensagem diferente de

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como posso fazer?

Comment: Olá Thais, não poste imagens do seu problema, dê preferência a colocar na pergunta, formatado, o ponto do código  onde ocorre o problema.

Comment: Invés de deixar o erro acontecer, talvez seja uma boa validar se o usuário já não possui uma empresa cadastrada.

Answer (score -1):

Tens duas hipóteses para apanhar esses erros (ambas podem ser usadas em simultâneo):

[Try/Catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

```
try
{
    // Code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // Handle ex
}
```

Ou utilizas o middleware nativo para tratamento de exceptions do .NET Core, que pode ser configurado através do método `UseExceptionHandler`. O boilerplate desse código já é gerado quando criamos um projeto pelo que poderás dar uma olhada nesse código e adaptar às tuas necessidades.